# Blender merge vertex to edge and remove additional edge

Tags: modeling

Hi I would like to make A and B coplanar by merging the edge on A onto B also the vertex in yellow should become a vertex on the edge of B and the edge of A should be merged with B edge I am going crazy! any idea? thanks[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you should create 3 loop cuts (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>), as marked by green lines, in order to fix your topology and make it easy to connect *A* with *B*.

[image]